# node.js redis asynchronous nature is confusing

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I'm using redis as below, and having trouble because `on('message')` seems to be called asynchrounously?

```
var subscriber = redis.createClient(port, host);
subscriber.subscribe('something');

subscriber.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log('got message');

    // I use generator here

    var generator = myGenerator();
    var waitFunciton = generator.next().value;

    waitFunction(function(err, data) {

        var result = generator.next().value;

        // do something with result
        console.log('returning result');
    });

});
```

I expect to see

```
'got message'  
'returning result'
'got message'  
'returning result'
```

in order.

Sometimes I see the following

```
'got message'
'got message'
'returning result'
```

See the missing 'returning result', and program is stuck.

How should I fix the program?

** edit **

```
var myGenerator = function* (arg) {
    main = {};
    main.messenger = new Backbone.Model();

    // performs something heavy

    // at the end of the heavy work,
    // main.messenger.trigger('done') is called

    _.extend(main, {
        wait: function (callback) {
            return main.messenger.once('done', callback);

        }
    });

    yield _.bind(main.wait, main);

    // since I have results at hand I'm returning result next time when I'm called

    var result;

    return result;

}
```

Comment: What `myGenerator` function does? Could you publish code of it?

Comment: I added the generator code

Comment: Oh that was typo while abstracting out the code.

Comment: What is `waitFunction`? It seems to be responsible for not firing the second `returning result`.

Comment: waitFunction is `main.wait` that myGenerator yields.

Answer (score 0):

Your code stucks because you're triggering `done` only once after first call of `myGenerator`. `next()` calls doesn't make the generator function to be executed from start so the `callback` with `log('returning result')` executed only once.

You can modify your `main.wait` function to check if your heavy computation is done already and call the callback immediately.

```
var myGenerator = function* (arg) {
    main = {};
    main.messenger = new Backbone.Model();

    // performs something heavy

    // at the end of the heavy work,
    // main.messenger.trigger('done') is called
    // main.messenger.set('computationDone', true);

    _.extend(main, {
        wait: function (callback) {
            if (main.messenger.get('computationDone') === true){
                 callback(); //filled with some data of course
            } else {
                return main.messenger.once('done', callback);
            }
        }
    });

    yield _.bind(main.wait, main);

    // since I have results at hand I'm returning result next time when I'm called

    var result;

    return result;
}
```